# Is there any parallel in Objective-C to C#'s yield keyword

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, iterator, yield

The first time I saw the `yield` keyword in C# I thought "yuck what a way to  junk up the language". Having grown since then and actually used the language I find it so pleasantly simple to express state logic that I'd like to use a similar approach in other development platforms.

I'm exploring Objective-C for some support utilities. Is there anything like the C# yield keyword for Objective-C?

Comment: `yield` gives me a warm fuzzy feeling, too. :)

Answer (score 6):

There's no real support for it in the language as far as I know, but here's [an implementation](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-30-generators-in-objective-c.html) someone took the time to build, might be helpful.

Comment: Use of blocks means it requires Mac OS X ≥10.6 or iPhone OS ≥4.0 (for official support.)

Answer (score 0):

the NSThread is a wrapper over pthread (according to the documentation)
conceptually if all you need is really to yield the thread, you can use pthread_yield().

Comment: In C# the `yield` keyword is used to create iterators; in which there is a method that has periodic means of "yielding" an item to the resulting iterator.  It's not really related to threads at all.

Comment: In high level terms yield is basically used for fast enumeration. What has pthread or NSThread to do with yield?